# Hibernate: Join 2 tables on a property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 tables with the following properties in the prod DB:

```
Bills table : id, customer_id, total 
Project table : id, customer_id
```

and `customer_id` is not a foreign key in any of the tables. Is there a way to join these tables with hibernate criteria? Tried using `DetachedCriteria`with `Subqueries` criteria. But was not able to join the tables!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change your mapping so that you have an additional mapping in your `Bills`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
private Project project;
```

Then you can use the standard way of joining in the criteria.

**Update**

If you can use HQL instead of Criteria.. then you can use the old style of join:

```
select b.name 
from Bills b, Project p 
where b.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

**Update 2**

If you have to use xml then specify your  as:

```
<many-to-one name="project" class="com.Project" ..>
   <column name="customer_id" property-ref="customer_id"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maciej, but unfortunately I cant edit the mappings and we are not using annotation based mappings. Is there any other way?

Comment: I guess I can. "<many-to-one name="client" column="client_id" class="Client" not-null="true" cascade="none" lazy="false" />". This is what I have in my bills hibernate.xml where Client is a different table

Comment: I have updated the post if you can use hql instead of criteria. The benefit would be that you can make it a NamedQuery and speed up the overall query time.

Comment: not really, but got the DetachedCriteria working. Thanks for the concern